# node is it possible to do if statements on events?

Tags: node.js, stream

Kind of like this?

```
if (this.on('pipe',function () {
  return true
}){
  //do something if piped 
}else{
  //do something if not piped
}
```

Because I want to do something different depending on whether or not something is piped to the function or not.

I'm guessing that won't work however because of how async node is, but I need something like that at least.

The main thing is I need something to run either OR but not both, if I were to implement a callback it won't work exactly like I want it to because whatever code I put after the `this.on` will still run, i need it to not run if `this.on` fires.

EDIT: Would `process.nextTick()` be what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, what I needed to do was Defer it to the next stack process with `process.nextTick()` so that it executed AFTER the .on callback was executed. so it's like this:

```
upload = function (path,file,callback){ 
  this.notpiped = true
  this.on('pipe',function () {
    this.notpiped = false
  })
  process.nextTick(function() {
      if(this.notpipe){
          cback(path,file,callback)
      }
  })
  this.end = function () {
    //handle piped data, eg, parse it, or set it or whatever and then use cback
  }
}

upload.prototype._write = (chunk, encoding, callback){
  this.data = this.data + chunk
}
```

so now this `.end` will fire like normal ONLY if `.pipe` gets called on it BUT if pipe doesn't get called then `.end` will never fire so it's ok to do it like this.

I can now have a function that can have data streamed to it, OR directly used depending on circumstances.

My actual function I'm using does a bit more then this and looks a little different but the concept is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I can't immagine the real situation where it's needed. I think you try to do something like this:

```
function mainContextFunction() {
  var isPiped = false;
  this.on('pipe', function(){isPiped = true;});

  function delayedExecution() {
    if (isPiped) ...;
    else ...
  }

  setTimeout(delayedExecution, 1000);
}

mainContextFunction();
```

Comment: I'm trying to copy mikeal's 'request' functionality of how you can both pipe to request or directly use request. Since I only want to run the code once I need to determine if it's being piped to or not so I can ensure that the code is run correctly, if it's really not possible then I will just have to create separate versions, one for streams and for non streams. I've tried looking through his code to figure out how he did it but I just can't see it.

Comment: You needs to check who is the caller of your function and if caller is EventEmitter go into if?